# How to obtain a channel "handle" without an associated type

Tags: go, channel

I have a backend (Go server) which services multiple frontends (web pages) and all requests/responses are handled via channels of specific types. Eg, each frontend is associated (on the backend) with a channel where responses are sent (type = chan<- Response).

I have recently implemented a login system where each frontend is associated with a user ID. To keep track of users I have a map:

```
logins map[chan<- Response]LoginData
```

Using this I can quickly look up things related to a frontend, such as permissions.  This all works fine.

However, to keep things safer and more modular I have moved all the Login stuff to a separate package.  This all works except for one gotcha - the logins map is keyed by the type "chan<- Response", but the Response type is defined in my main package and I don't want to expose it to the Login package. (I don't think I could anyway as it would create a circular reference.)

I only want to use the "chan<- Response" as a handle type in the Login package - I don't need to write to that channel from there. I tried converting the channel to an unsafe.Pointer but that is not allowed by the compiler.  On the other hand I can't use a pointer to the channel variable  (*chan<- Response) as the handle as the channel is stored in several places so the channel variable will have different addresses.

I also tried casting to a different type of chan such as chan int and chan interface{} but the compiler does not like that. There does not seem to be any way to convert a channel into a "generic" channel.

I really just want the address of the channel's internal data - like you get when you fmt.Printf a channel with %v.  The best I can come up with is to use a string like this:

```
var c chan<- Response = ...
var userID = "steve"
loginKey = fmt.Sprint(c)
Login.Add(loginKey, userID)
```

I'm not sure this is valid but seems to work, but it seems to me there should be a better way.

Comment: You could use `interface {}`  as a type

Comment: "the Response type is defined in my main package" - this is a design flaw. The `main` package should do as little as possible, and it *definitely* shouldn't define types, for exactly the reason you're seeing here.

Comment: Thanks @Adrian for reading and understanding (and not down-voting what is a reasonable question I think :). I agree absolutely with your comment, but this project started as one main package and grew. I have been trying to separate parts of it into internal packages (as in this question) I will heed your advice and try to work out how to move the types into separate packages.

Answer (score 0):

> On the other hand I can't use a pointer to the channel variable (*chan<- Response) as the handle as the channel is stored in several places so the channel variable will have different addresses.

But this is the only (halfway acceptable solution): Do not pass around a `chan Response` but a `*(chan Response)` (adding directions to your likings). Everything else is crap. Best thing to do is hiding this chan Response in a type.

Comment: Thanks.  You are right it should be easy enough to have one chan variable and pass around a pointer to it. It just seems a bit redundant as I think a channel variable is essentially just a pointer to the real channel.

I agree the best thing is to create a new type but it makes little sense to declare it in my Login package and I can't declare it in the main package (circular ref), so I guess I need to put it in a new package that I import into main and Login packages.